# Public vs src directories (vue-cli)

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

The default directory structure when using vue-cli contains a 'public' directory and 'src' directory. The public directory contains index.html. What exactly is the purpose of putting index.html in the public directory instead of src? What are other examples of files that should go in public?

Comment: The answer to your question is [documented here on the vue-cli website](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files placed in the public folder are static and will not be processed by webpack.

"Placed in the public directory and referenced via absolute paths. These assets will simply be copied and not go through webpack"

Source: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling

Example may include: Favicon, icons for PWA, robots.txt, manifest.json... Just to name a few.

Comment: It's not complete true, since `public/index.html` is a template that will be processed with html-webpack-plugin. So there is some confusion/mess.

Comment: Just for clarity, it will be injected with the app files per config instructions. So you are correct that it will be processed prior to being copied over, but your static changes to the index.html file will be left intact.